# Facebook Integration in new Android facebook sdk 3.5

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am unable to authorize my android app with facebook as well done in previous sdk 3.0.1 that is deprecated.
While I click to login it navigates to existing facebook page in some device or in some device a permission popup opens and when I click ok it cancels the request.

These all cases occurs if I have already installed face-book application in my device.

Comment: did u register ur app on facebook and have proper hash key?

Comment: I have created app on faceb-ook with proper keyHash But how can I register it Face-book after creation.

Comment: But this is working while using old version of Android Facebook SDk.

Comment: can you show us the whole code?

Comment: I have used the sample that in facebook-android-sdk-3.5 namespace as SessionLoginSample And I am getting error : Failed to find provider info com.facebook.katana.provider.platformProvider

Comment: I have used the sample that in facebook-android-sdk-3.5

Comment: just post your manifest.xml and your main activity..i cannot predict your problem on my own..make sure you did have set internet permission